# Data is not posting in Angularjs to WebApi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Angular code is below. Please look if I am missing something in post request -

```
<script>   
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("myControllerSubmit", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        var Employee = { empID: $scope.empId, Name: $scope.empName, Gender: $scope.empGender }
        $http(
        {
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost:58365/home/saveEmpData',
          data:  Employee,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'                       }   
        }).success(function (response,status,headers,config) {
              $scope.data1 = response.data;
        })
    }
})
</script>
```

In webApi I am getting null Employee object

```
[HttpPost]
public void saveEmpData( Employee emp)
{
    if (emp.Name != null)
    {
        var objempList = new DAL();
        objempList.saveData(emp);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mark Rajcok help me.

Comment: pass `data: {emp : Employee}`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `[FromBody]` Attribute before `emp` parameter to get data from posted request.

```
public void saveEmpData([FromBody] Employee emp)
```

Comment: i tried [FromBody] but its not helpful...still m getting null object

Comment: try ` data:  angular.fromJson(Employee)`

Comment: @pankaj..angular.fromJson(Employee) also not working

Answer (score 0):

The content type x-www-form-urlencoded is used when sending body content as one giant string. Read Matts great answer about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data) 
In your case you want to send an object and then its more suitable to use the content type json.
I would change the submit as below and try again

```
    <script>   

          var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

        .controller("myControllerSubmit", function ($scope, $http) {

            $scope.submit = function () {
                var Employee = { empID: $scope.empId, Name: $scope.empName, Gender: $scope.empGender }
                $http(
              {
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: 'http://localhost:58365/home/saveEmpData',
                  data:  JSON.stringify(Employee),
                  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'                       }   
              }).success(function (response,status,headers,config) {
                  $scope.data1 = response.data;
              })
            }
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: .its giving error like - 'angular.js:12520 ReferenceError: json is not defined'

Comment: @MukulSharma sorry, You need to use JSON instead of json. Updated my answer

Comment: now i am getting this error - XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:58365/home/saveEmpData. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Comment: @MukulSharma are the url correct? You tagged web-api but so shouldn't the url be /api/home? Please provide the complete code of the web api controller class where the method saveEmpData is defined.

Comment: i checked it in IE its working properly. I think this error is browser specific

Comment: @MukulSharma How did you checked it in IE? Did the post method work in IE only?

Comment: i think IE avoid Preflight request.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this..

          <script>   

                  var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

                .controller("myControllerSubmit", function ($scope, $http) {

                    $scope.submit = function () {
                          var Employee = { empID: $scope.empId, Name: $scope.empName, Gender: $scope.empGender }
                         $http.post( 'http://localhost:58365/home/saveEmpData', json.Stringify(Employee) ).success(function (response,status,headers,config) {
                          $scope.data1 = response.data;
                        }).error (function(){
                              alert("error")
                          });
                    }
                })

                 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want model binding to occur through json, You have to change the variable to the same name as it is in Web api `emp`.

```
<script>   

              var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

            .controller("myControllerSubmit", function ($scope, $http) {

                $scope.submit = function () {
                    var Employee = { empID: $scope.empId, Name: $scope.empName, Gender: $scope.empGender }
                    $http(
                  {
                      method: 'POST',
                      url: 'http://localhost:58365/home/saveEmpData',
                      data:  {emp: Employee},
                      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'                       }   
                  }).success(function (response,status,headers,config) {
                      $scope.data1 = response.data;
                  })
                }
            })

             </script>
```

That will solve your issue hopefully

Comment: @Umair..if i use your code i am getting this error - XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:58365/home/saveEmpData. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Comment: I have edited the code. Just changed this line. data:  Employee to data: {emp: Employee}

Answer (score 0):

you made a mistake here in assigning the properties.
Replace with this

```
var Employee = { "empID": $scope.empId, "Name": $scope.empName, "Gender": $scope.empGender }
```

Comment: if your finding a trouble even with this! let me know the error. coz I suffered with this kind of null reference exception for 4 days.

Comment: @Aravind...XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:58365/home/saveEmpData. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Comment: expose your api method completely